# How do I install things on a VPS?

Tags: vps

I just bought a VPS, installed Ubuntu 11 with LAMP, and now I'm totally lost.

I want to install something like WHM (I'm new to this so I'm not sure what exactly). I've used cPanel in the past when administering websites, so my first thought is to install an open source alternative like zPanel.

My understanding:

1. Download installation file.
2. Upload file to VPN
3. Install it
4. Return to Serverfault.com to figure out how to use it

So I'm stuck at point 2. how do I get the zPanel on to my VPS to install it? I'd do it with FTP, but I don't know how to set up an FTP account without a cPanel.

Comment: You don't even need to upload to your VPS as you can download straight on to it. There appears to be extensive documentation on how to install zpanel on Ubuntu here http://www.zpanel.co.uk/Install%20ZPanel%206%20ubuntu.htm .

Comment: As you are so new to Ubuntu then you really should spend some time with the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) and also be aware that there is http://askubuntu.com an SE site for Ubuntu enthusiasts.

Comment: Am I getting downvoted because I'm not knowledgeable on this topic, or because it's a bad question?

Comment: @brentonstrine  Not that I downvoted it, but I'm certain it's because the question shows a lack of effort into researching the issue on your own.  If the answer to the question is "read the manual" or "there are 215,000,000 Google results for how to do this," then it's going to get downvoted here, much like (I'd hope) a question over at StackOverflow amounting to ~"how do I compile my code?" would be downvoted.  This question is fairly analogous to that, from an SA standpoint.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Thanks. I've since realized I shouldn't be at serverfault right now. The 215x10^15 Google results are sometimes impossible to wade through when you don't even know how to phrase the question.

Comment: @brentonstrine  No argument about wading through Google results to sort the crap from the useful, particularly when your knowledge is shaky to begin with.  I'd suggest that you'll get the most utility out of this site by first reading the documentation (or as much of the relevant docs you can stomach), trying to do whatever it is and then coming back here to either search for a solution or ask a question when you hit a specific stumbling block (provided that particular stumbling block doesn't have a plethora of easily found solutions online).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have active SSH connection on your VPS, you can upload it via SCP (for example you can use WinSCP for windows) or you can use this instruction: http://planet.zpanelcp.com/doku.php?id=zpanel_6:articles:installation:zpanel_6.1.x_ubuntu

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was a very simple and straightforward question, and apparently so did you. I guess the mods want me to know the answers to things before I ask.

Comment: No problem ;) I don't know why mod close your topic, it's normal question.

Comment: @brentonstrine You are kind of correct. Serverfault is for professional system administrators and as such we expect a certain level of competence. At this time you fall below that line and we'll find it difficult to help you as you don't even have the basics. What you really need is education not an Q&A site.

Comment: Got it. I had posted on StackOverflow and was directed here. I've since been directed to Linux sites. I am educating myself as I go--just need to ask questions in the right place. Sorry!